# Navigate/refresh to page from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm writing application and I have problem with NavigateService class.
Navigate works when I use it in 'parent' class for examlpe:

```
   MainPage.xaml
   MainPage.xaml.cs 
   Something.cs
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
//NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); <-- this works
Something neww = new Something();
```

Something.cs:

```
public partial class Something : PhoneApplicationPage {
public Something() {
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
}
```

This doesnt work and I get exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   By catch:
>   object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Can you ensure `NavigationService` is not null?

Comment: if (this.NavigationService == null)
MessageBox.Show("null");
Is null

Comment: `Tk000`: does this work `new Uri("MainPage.xaml")`? Also, where is Something() created?

Comment: Yes, in mainpage all Navigates works, but not in Something constructor :/

Comment: hmm, I still dont have idea how i can do this refresh or forward :/

Comment: Solution is:
(App.Current as App).RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Navigate to a Page from a class by using the PhoneApplicationFrame

```
  (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/PivotPage1.xaml",
            UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

The pages *NavigationService* property validates that the host of the control supports navigation and returns the hosts navigation service.

In your case you are just creating the Something page, but you are never putting it into a frame, so it has no host and its *NavigationService* property returns null.

---

Furthermore:
You can use the *App.RootFrame* to trigger navigation anyway, but you should think if that is really a good thing to do: Why are you even creating a page in Code and not let navigation handle it?